# Find Duplicate String Elements In An Array & Count Occurence of that elecment in java

Tags: java, arrays

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strArray = { "Islamabad", "Gilgit", "Nawabshah", "Karachi",
            "Abbotabad", "Gilgit", "Hyderabad", "Islamabad", "Lahore",
            "Hyderabad", "Sukkur", "Faisalabad", "Kohat", "Faisalabad",
            "Faisalabad", "Bhakkar", "Faisalabad", "Lahore", "Abbotabad",
            "Attock", "Karachi", "Rawalpindi", "Nawab Shah", "Abbotabad",
            "Sukkur", "Attock", "Multan", "Faisalabad", "Multan", "Sukkur" };
    System.out.println("Length : " + strArray.length);

    Arrays.sort(strArray);

    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < strArray.length; j++) {
            if ((strArray[i].equals(strArray[j])) && (i != j)) {
                System.out.println("Duplicate Element is : " + strArray[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < strArray.length; i++) {
        // If same integer is already present then add method will return
        // FALSE
        if (set.add(strArray[i]) == false) {
            System.out.println("Duplicate element found : " + strArray[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

---

[I have tried both methods following this but none of them give any accurate result,  it doesn't work for the my number of array elements](http://javaconceptoftheday.com/java-program-to-find-duplicate-elements-in-an-array/)

Comment: that link leads me to nowhere

Comment: it didnt give me a @nullpointer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: Your example code contains no attempt to count elements. Make an attempt to do the work yourself first. If you have trouble, then ask a specific question.

Comment: Why are you using a HashSet?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using `Java 8` you can use [Stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html) and [Collectors](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html):

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] strArray = { "Islamabad", "Gilgit", "Nawabshah", "Karachi",
            "Abbotabad", "Gilgit", "Hyderabad", "Islamabad", "Lahore",
            "Hyderabad", "Sukkur", "Faisalabad", "Kohat", "Faisalabad",
            "Faisalabad", "Bhakkar", "Faisalabad", "Lahore", "Abbotabad",
            "Attock", "Karachi", "Rawalpindi", "Nawab Shah", "Abbotabad",
            "Sukkur", "Attock", "Multan", "Faisalabad", "Multan", "Sukkur" };

    System.out.format("The length of the array is: %d%n%n", strArray.length);

    System.out.println("Duplicate String Elements and their count is shown below:");

    Arrays.stream(strArray)
      .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s))
      .forEach((k, v) -> {if(v.size() > 1) System.out.println(k+" "+v.size());});

  }
}
```

Output:

```
The length of the array is: 30

Duplicate String Elements and their count is shown below:
Faisalabad 5
Gilgit 2
Islamabad 2
Hyderabad 2
Attock 2
Karachi 2
Multan 2
Lahore 2
Sukkur 3
Abbotabad 3
```

Try it [here!](https://repl.it/ErUo/0)

Answer (score 0):

I am just going to edit your code to print number of duplicates that are occuring for a String:

```
static int count;
int i,j;
 for ( i = 0; i < strArray.length - 1; i++) {
       count=0;
    for ( j = i + 1; j < strArray.length; j++) {
        if ((strArray[i].equals(strArray[j])) && (i != j)) {
            count++;
        }
    }
 System.out.println("Duplicate Element is : " + strArray[j]+"Its occurrences are:"+count);
}
```

Comment: Not sure how would this compile because at strArray[j] how does it know what "j" is?

Comment: Actually j will point to the String that comes after to the String pointed by i, for-ex: if i="Islamabad" then j points to "Gilgit", now they are not equal so j will now point to String next to "Gilgit", in this case is-"Nawabshah", henceforth the value of i is compared with value of j untill j points to last String in the array.

Comment: I get that. My question is how does it know what "j" is in the print statement because the scope of j is only upto the previous braces.

Comment: This compiles for you?

Comment: Oh I am extremely sorry for my silly mistake i should have declared that variable outside of the loops for increasing thier scopes. thank you very much @Anurag Joshi for pointing out my mistake, i will edit it

Comment: does it compile now?

Comment: assign both i,j to 0

Comment: otherwise it doesn't know where to start from!

Comment: Yes it should compile!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130729/discussion-between-anurag-joshi-and-manish-sakpal).

Comment: It didn't. Gave me java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException